# iOS statusbar overlay phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing iOS app with PhoneGap (Cordova) and my problem is that status bar is overlaying my webview/application:

[image]

I've added preferences in my config.xml file but these are not working:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#0ff000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this way:
With cordova-plugin-statusbar installed, added this line to config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
```

and then in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady(){
            StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Installation Command for **[Status bar Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

**StatusBarOverlaysWebView (boolean, defaults to true).** On iOS 7, make the statusbar overlay or not overlay the WebView at startup.
 Add this line in your **config.xml**

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

Please read [official documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Check out Step 3: at the bottom of the page at this link...

https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/handlebars-templates.html

It actually looks pretty identical to what you did, but also involves a node plugin for the status bar issue.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Hopefully it helps.